# how insert data into database from table in jsp

Tags: html, mysql, database, jsp

Why not data store into database in jsp. find error in the following  the code. I want to fetch data from form fields and get it from jsp page and store into database.

database name=test table name=info columns name=first_name,last_name

```
<%@page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"  %> 
<%@page import="javax.servlet.*,javax.servlet.http.*" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>connection with database</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        String f_name = request.getParameter("f");
       String l_name = request.getParameter("l");
        <sql:setDataSource var="sqldata" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" user="root" password="" />
        <sql:update dataSource="${sqldata}" var="result1" >
            INSERT INTO info(first_name,last_name)VALUES('f_name','l_name');
        </sql:update>--%>


            <input type="text" name="f" /><br />
             <input type="text" name="l" /><br />
             <input type='submit' />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your connect string says mysql, so I changed into it from SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Haven't touched JSP for a long time. If my memory is correct, shouldn't it be like this?

```
<%@page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"  %> 
<%@page import="javax.servlet.*,javax.servlet.http.*" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%        
      String f_name = request.getParameter("f");          
      String l_name = request.getParameter("l");
      pageContext.setAttribute("f_name", f_name);
      pageContext.setAttribute("l_name", l_name);
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>connection with database</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:if test="${f_name != null}">
        <sql:setDataSource var="sqldata" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" user="root" password="" />
        <sql:update dataSource="${sqldata}" var="result1">
            INSERT INTO info (first_name,last_name) VALUES (?,?);
            <sql:param value="${f_name}" />
            <sql:param value="${l_name}" />
        </sql:update>
        </c:if>

            <input type="text" name="f" /><br />
            <input type="text" name="l" /><br />
            <input type='submit' />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: 
            INSERT INTO infor (first_name,last_name) VALUES (?,?);
            
            
        : Column 'first_name' cannot be null
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:601)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)

Comment: so much thanks sir .it is work proper.God bless you and your family

Comment: sir please describe the function of pageContext and <c: if .thanks

Comment: <c:if> is to check null as your data column does not allow null. pageContext.setAttribute is just make the variable accessible within context of current page by JSTL.

Comment: what's that (?,?) please describe shortly .thank you sir

Comment: sql parameter. it is expecting 2 parameters.